# I can't go into pose mode or object mode at all

Tags: animation

I'm pretty new to blender and I just started getting into animation. I downloaded the fully rigged character "Hugo" from BlenderKit but I can't seem to be able to go into pose mode or object mode at all and it doesn't even show up in the dropdown menu. Just Object Mode. Any help would be great!

Comment: Please add some images of what you are facing to your question to make it clear.To go into pose mode make sure that you have selected the armature

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you haven't selected an object yet. Make sure to click and select the rig then clicking this button and it should appear. [image]